# Good practice to create URIs out of Identifier

Tags: namespaces, uri, rdf, semantic-web

I have several resources which I want to model with RDF, each of them has an unique identifier (GPS coordinates in the DMS format.

- 36.54.01E.25.28.44N
- 150.18.38.9E.2.40.47.5S
- ...

Now I want to create URIs for each of them. What is considered best practice in this case? Can Is imply append it to my namespace URI or shouldn't I do this because of the dots?

Comment: This question was asked at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17735/good-practice-to-create-uris-out-of-identifier where other complementary answers are found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dots are a perfectly legitimate character to find in a URI, so yes, what you're suggesting would be syntactically OK as a URI.

I'm not aware of *best practice* as such, in this area, but there's a very good collection of linked data patterns by Leigh Dodds and Ian Davis, which includes a section on [identifiers](http://patterns.dataincubator.org/book/identifier-patterns.html) which may be useful for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is OK to do and I am "guilty" of using uri's like this myself.

**However**: rdf purists might challenge this.  There could be many things at one physical location.  This is OK(ish) as long as you put it under *your own namespace* (e.g. "http://kool.rdfsite.Mahondi.net/gps/36.54... etc")

RDF stores are almost always indexed by the combination of predicate,object.  If you name an appropriate predicate (again your own namespace if you wish) and use the DMS as the object, it will still be just one fast indexed lookup to find the resource which I'm suggesting could be a blank node.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of 'RDF purity', really, since there's no necessary link between the characters in a URI and the thing it refers to (the URI is an 'opaque identifier').  Thus I could write `<http://my.ns/36.54.01E.25.28.44N> a ns:Book; dc:creator "Kernighan and Ritchie".` and it becomes a name for K&R. It's an eccentric name for the book, certainly, but it's my namespace so I get to decide what the URI refers to.

Comment: @NormanGray I said "This is OK" but OP solicited advice on best practice.  Your "eccentric" name for the book might be legal buy not best practice.  But that is only my opinion and it is your namespace to do as you wish.

Comment: you're right: I'm maybe guilty of riding a hobbyhorse, here! I suppose the 'practice' issue I'm thinking of is that the algorithm for minting URIs in your namespace has to be something that's convenient and unique for the things being named (but isn't intrinsically meaningful). So naming things based on coordinates is sensible if and (as you point out) only if there's guaranteed to be only one thing there. If that's true of the set of things being named (eg buildings), this might be fine practice, if not (eg books!) then not. But perhaps it's practice rather than purity.